# Fastest way to read a text file

Tags: java, java-io

What's the fastest way to read a text file for processing?
The input to the program from the file has to be in ascii to do some text processing.
Which should be faster? Using a BufferedReader or BufferedInputStream?

Example:

```
in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFileName));
char[] buffer = new char[8*1024];
while((len = in.read(buffer))>=0) {
       //format text
}

OR
in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inFileName));
byte[] buffer = new byte[8*1024];
while((len = in.read(buffer))>=0) {
    String str = new String(bytes, "ISO-8859-1");
    char [] chars = str.toCharArray();
     //format text
}
```

I timed this piece of code and could not see much of a difference. I was wondering if anyone had any input depending on the size of the file.

Comment: What size was your file?

Comment: So...  Why don't you time it using a HUGE file?

Comment: Size of file is 1 MB.

Comment: I wanted to know what is best in theory - sounds like reading in bytes should be faster. But if you have to re-format into string - does that make sense?

Comment: @user3096748 generally if you file size is small (can be easily loaded in memory) it literally wouldn't make any difference how you read it. It is only when you start dealing with gigabyte and petabyte files you have to start thinking about other scaling algorithms

Answer (score 0):

For a 1MB file it will hardly make any difference. Both those versions will execute in about a second. I would be more concerned about the extra `String` and `char[]` creation in the second version from the GC and memory usage point of view.